# Byte to Character Conversion for a Telnet Stream

Tags: c#, byte, ascii, telnet

I am getting a stream of byte data from a telnet session via `TcpClient.GetStream().ReadByte()`. I am then converting this byte data to ASCII via `char` casting. The data comes through fine, but with a lot of extra junk like `1[01;001H[0k[01.`

Anyone have any idea what this extra junk might be?

UPDATE
More detailed response stream below

1[01;001H[0K[01;017H[0;1;4mTitle of Page Here[0;1m[0;1m[02;001H[02;051H[0KWed Mar 28, 2012 03:03 pm[02;051HDate Time Here[0J[03;001H[0J[23;001H[0J[0;1;7mPrompt Here[P]-- [0;1m[23;044H

When it should read

Title of Page Here
Date Time Here

Prompt Here

Comment: Show your current code, please.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Why are you converting it by char casting, there are methods to convert entire byte[]'s into a string.  You don't seem to understand what is being transmited.

Comment: Are you sure your input data contains only ASCII characters?

Comment: What kind of data? Text? Which encoding? And the extra junk, does it appear only in certain places, say at the end of blocks of 512 normal bytes or something...

Comment: That looks like terminal escape sequences. Keep in mind that many systems will assume that the consumer of a console program is a terminal (or nowadays a terminal emulator), so you're stuck in a 1970s text stream API.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm reading a telnet response from a tcpclient, which reads bytes in decimal format. They are read byte by byte to weed out and respond to the telnet protocol.

Comment: @JonathanWood I'm filtering the data to convert and display only decimal values between 31 and 128 and values equivalent to things like linefeed or tab for formatting.

Comment: @Joey That sounds promising. How could I check for and filter out those escape sequences? They seem to be intermingled with the actually data I want. I'm adding a more detailed response above for reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parts of the 'junk' you're seeing are part of the Telnet protocol. The remote is trying to negotiate some options with you, and may also send you some other commands (although that's relatively rare in practice). See the `TELNET COMMAND STRUCTURE` section of the [applicable RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) for the exact format and meaning of all possible commands.

In most cases, you'll be able to simply ignore any Telnet commands (including option negotiation) received, but you do have to filter them: as you discovered, simply treating a Telnet session as a clean TCP stream won't work.

In addition to protocol-level options, the remote may also assume you're a terminal, and send escape sequences to ensure the data is properly displayed. Interpreting or filtering those codes will depend on the type of terminal the remote is configured to use -- it's not unlikely you'll encounter a [VT100](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm), for example.

There's no real need to delve too deeply into the specs, by the way: it's entirely feasible to use something pre-built like this [minimalistic Telnet library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library) to deal with the most important details for you.

**EDIT, 29 March 2012:** The additional examples of the 'junk' you're seeing confirm that the remote is treating you as a VT100. For example: `[0;1;4mTitle of Page Here` corresponds to `Set Attribute Mode: <ESC>[{attr1};...;{attrn}m` and tries to make the page title appear bright (1) and underlined (4).

Simplest option here: as soon as you see an ESCape character (ASCII 27), ignore everything after that up to and including the first character that isn't in the list `[;0123456789`. That will strip the most common VT100 codes: there are a few that may require special handling, but those are rare, and anyway, you have the specs now.

But even if you strip the control codes, you may still end up with an unparseable data stream, especially if the host tries to maintain a fancy screen layout. For example, it may randomly update a status field (e.g. a clock) in the middle of a stream of values that you're interested in. If that's the case, you'll need a (virtual) VT100 emulator annex screen scraper. Those kinds of solutions mostly seem to involve expensive commercial software, although [libvt100 - A purely .net/C# library for parsing a VT100/ANSI stream](http://code.google.com/p/libvt100/) may work for you.

Comment: Actually, minimalistic Telnet is exactly what I'm using. I've adapted it to also only display decimal values from the byte stream between 31 and 128 as well as the special characters like tab and linefeed for formatting purposes. I'm still getting junk data though. Perhaps it is the terminal escape sequences? How would I check for that? Also, above I'm adding an example of the output in more detail.

Comment: Is there anything that denotes an end to the escaped sequence? I'm seeing the byte 27 coming through before the format data, but the ending bytes all seem different. My only concern is possibly clipping off some of the information I need. Also h,m and a few others are used in the sequence. I'd rather like to get rid of those in the junk, but not in my general ASCII display (I need to be able to accurately parse the response).

Comment: I found a list of ASCII ANSI escape sequences here: http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php I should be able to use this to filter out the exact sequences after the escape byte. Thanks for all the help everyone! I had no clue wehre this mess was coming from.